# How can I fake something which returns different answers over time using FakeItEasy?

Tags: fakeiteasy

I'm trying to fake a sealed external audio source using FakeItEasy.

I've wrapped the audio source and successfully faked the wrapper, so I know the basics are right. Here's the bit I'm currently stuck on:

The audio source returns isPlaying = true after it's been called with Play(). isPlaying will remain true until the audio clip has finished playing at which point it'll return to false.

I can fake the first part of this with the following code:

```
A.CallTo(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.Play())
    .Invokes(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying = true)
```

Which successfully fakes isPlaying being true after the Play function is called. What I'd like to do is then delay a certain time and then make it return false to simulate what happens after the clip has finished playing.

I tried

```
    A.CallTo(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.Play())
        .Invokes(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying = true)
        .Then
        .Invokes(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying = false);
```

with the idea that a call to isPlaying would return true the first time it was called after Play() was called, and return false the second time, but got no joy.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would probably work if `Play` were called more than once, since you're configuring what Play does (although I think you switched the true and false). I'm guessing from the question that `Play` is only called once. In that case, you want Play to perform an action that will set up [changing behaviour between calls to isPlaying](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing-behavior-between-calls/).

Consider the approach in this passing test, where `Play` causes `isPlaying` to return `true` exactly once (the default behaviour for an unconfigured bool-returning Fake's method is to return `false`):

```cs
public interface IAudioSourceWrapper {
    public bool isPlaying {get;set;}
    public void Play();
}

[Fact]
public void PlayThenDoNotPlay()
{
    var fakeAudioSourceWrapper = A.Fake<IAudioSourceWrapper>();
    A.CallTo(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.Play())
        .Invokes(() => {
            A.CallTo(() => fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying).Returns(true).Once();
        });

    fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying.Should().Be(false);
    fakeAudioSourceWrapper.Play();
    fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying.Should().Be(true);
    fakeAudioSourceWrapper.isPlaying.Should().Be(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Question edited to fix the true/false mixup...